# How to scroll to an element after asyncData?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm getting some data via `asyncData` and after the items are displayed, the website has to scroll to an element.

```
methods: {
    scrollTo() {
        // ScrollTo Element...
    }
},
asyncData({ env, params }) {
    return axios.get(`${env.cockpit.apiUrl}/collections/get/kalender`)
    .then(({data}) => {
        return {
            items
        }
    })
}
```

`this.scrollTo()` is not available in `asyncData`.

If I use a timeout in the `mounted()` method, it works. Without a timeout it doesn't.

```
mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.scrollTo()
    }, 500)
}
```

But I think, this is not the right way. The same thing with `this.$nextTick` is not working, either.

What is the right way to scroll to an element after getting the data via `asyncData()`?

Comment: Scrolling from your mounted hook should work, as the `asyncData` block is executed on the server and the data is already merged, once mounted gets called on the client-side. I suspect the error might be in your `scrollTo` implementation, can you provide the code for that as well?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using events i'm not too sure about event dispatching in vue, in angular we have:

`$scope.$broadcast('event-name', data)`

`$scope.$on('event-name', () => {})`

but I'll show in you vanilla js so you can learn how it works under the hood.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

We'll want to register the event to the window or even better the element that should be targeted.

```
const onDataFetched = new Event('on-kalender-fetched');
    
methods: {
   scrollTo() {
     // ScrollTo Element...
   }
},
        
        
asyncData({ env, params }) {
   return axios.get(`${env.cockpit.apiUrl}/collections/get/kalender`)
      .then(({data}) => {
         return {
           items
         }
       })
       .finally(items => window.dispatchEvent('on-kalender-fetched', items))
}
```

next we'll want to set up the listener in your mounted function you'll want to avoid timeouts as what if they're on a slow connection and it takes more than half a second its much more reliable this way.

```
 mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('on-kalender-fetched', () => this.scrollTo(), false);
 }
```

finally we want to dispatch the event when the request has finished using window or an element.dispatchEvent('name-of-event', dataToSend)

**EDIT:**

how vue does event dispatching

> ```
> this.$emit('myEvent')
> ```
>
> Listening to the kebab-cased version will have no effect:
>
> ```
> <my-component v-on:my-event="doSomething"></my-component>
> ```
>
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: Thanks. This is a good answer. I tried your solution, but I don't have access on `this` in asyncData.

_You do NOT have access of the component instance through this inside asyncData because it is called before initiating the component._ https://nuxtjs.org/api/

Comment: and fyi you dont need access to the comenent you just need to beable to emit an event